# Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Not sure where I went wrong here:

**test.js**

```
let chai = require('chai'),
    should = chai.should(),
    game = require('../src/game');

    it('should be able to start the game', () => {
        game.start();

        game.started.should.be.true;
    });
```

**game.js**

```
var board = require('./board'),
    hasStarted = false;

module.exports = {
    start: start,
    started: hasStarted
};

function start(){
    hasStarted = true;
};
```

for the test I get the assertion error:

```
AssertionError: expected false to be true
```

I thought I had set it in my start() method so why is my test still failing with false?

Answer (score 4):

You've assigned initial value of `hasStarted` to your module exports, it didn't change with a call to `start()`.

Use a function to retrieve it instead of a variable, i.e.:

```
module.exports = {
    start: start,
    started: function() { return hasStarted; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the local variable you have used is a primitive type it doesn't reflect after calling start method.Primitive types in js are passed by value.

```
var hasStarted = {
    isStarted: false
};
var game = {
    start: start,
    started: hasStarted
};

function start() {
    hasStarted.isStarted = true;
};

module.exports = game;
```

This will work has you expect